# Javascript: как прервать выполнение любого кода в рамках текущего окна?

Tags: javascript, html, selenium, тестирование, браузер

Есть простейшая страница, вот ее код:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <script>
      setTimeout(function(){
        document.body.innerHTML += 'sleeped 10 secs';
      },10000);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Необходимо неким сторонним скриптом, по факту - просто выполненным в консоли браузера, остановить выполнение кода, который в странице, да и вообще любого кода, который на текущий момент выполняется, например из подгруженных сторонних js-библиотек.

Это возможно в принципе? И если да, то как это реализовать?

*UPD: имеется ввиду не ручная остановка скрипта, а некая автоматизированная, через запуск чего-либо в консоли средствами Selenium, например. Так-то понятно, что можно и точку остановки сделать, и много чего еще. Но интересно другое - как "автоматическим" образом сказать браузеру, что нужно остановить выполнение любого JS в рамках текущего окна.*

Comment: никак это не реализовать.

Comment: `alert` покажет модальное окно, но остановит главный поток, пока не закроете окно)

Comment: @ThisMan, подозреваю, это немного не то, что хотел автор вопроса :)

Comment: @Grundy скорее всего, но это единственный вариант, может от отчаянья решится на него)

Comment: @ThisMan, ну не, проще уж тогда нажать паузу в dev-tools

Comment: @Grundy как раз скорее всего это нужный вариант. Из тегов наверное должно было стать понятно, что интересно реализовывать это все кодом, руками к браузеру не подобраться просто физически. Сейчас вынесу инфу об этом в вопрос.

Comment: @StanislavBelichenko проблема в том, что вы программно это окно потом не закроете(

Comment: @StanislavBelichenko, а в селениуме разве ничего встроенного нет? Не уверен, но возможно могут быть проблемы с возвратом после alert

Comment: @ThisMan я потом просто его закрою через Selenium, прибив все что там существует вообще.

Comment: а зачем это вообще?

Comment: @Grundy - встроенного там ничего нет, по крайней мере гуглеж не помог. При этом у меня ограничение - я работаю с ним через facebook/php-webdriver. А так да, там есть проблемы с alert, возможно это будет вариант.

Comment: @ThisMan если коротко, то после того как мы сделали что-то на некоей странице через Selenium, мы можем захотеть получить код этой страницы. Но у нее могут быть некоторые собственные соображения что делать, например - пойти по js-редиректу куда-то. Нам это не нужно.

Comment: @StanislavBelichenko, по-моему ты выбрал не совсем верный подход, если тебе нужен код, ты разве его через тот же selenium Не можешь получить? Мне кажется, по крайней мере для редиректа стоит попробовать посмотреть в сторону событий, типа [beforeNavigateTo](https://facebook.github.io/php-webdriver/latest/Facebook/WebDriver/WebDriverEventListener.html)

Comment: @Grundy Я могу и получаю его именно через Selenium, проблема в том, что пока там крутятся редиректы или еще что происходит, код не отдается. И мы не всегда знаем, что там внутри происходит вообще, в том числе куда будет редирект. В общем просто нужно то, что описано в вопросе, все варианты уже пройдены :-)

Comment: Если кому-то интересно, то решил конкретно свою задачу (не описанную) через метод php-webdriver manage()->timeouts()->pageLoadTimeout($secs) - она использует метод Selenium setTimeout (не путать с методом JS). В итоге вебдрайвер гарантированно отвисает даже если на управляемой им странице крутится вечный редирект.

В ответы выносить не буду, так как основной вопрос был совсем не о том, по сути.